# Custom file name while keeping extension

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

Following this part of the docs:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/filesystem#file-uploads

I'm trying to store a file (an image) and specify a custom file name, but I don't want to change the extension.

If I do:

```
$request->file('avatar')->storeAs('avatars', 'custom_file_name');
```

The file will save as `custom_file_name` (with no extension), rather than `custom_file_name.png`).

How can I specify a custom file name while keeping the original file extension?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get extension of uploaded file with:

```
$extension = $request->photo->extension();
```

And apply it manually to the stored file name.

> The `UploadedFile` class also contains methods for accessing the file's fully-qualified path and its extension. The `extension` method will attempt to guess the file's extension based on its contents.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#files

Answer (score 1):

The code below checks if request has a file by id/name avatar and then stores it with custom_name.{uploaded_files_extension}

```
 if($request->hasFile('avatar')) {
                $imgfile = Input::file('avatar');
                $custom_name = 'custom_name'.$imgfile->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $request->file('avatar')->storeAs('avatars', $custom_name);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to buttress  @alexey-mezenin answer,
you might have issue adding the extension

```
  //get extension
  $extension = $request->file('featured_img')->extension();

 $request->file('featured_img')->storeAs('/public/album',$post->title.'.'.$extension);
```

With that you can have a complete code stored in your /storage/public/album