# Why is Laravel renaming the file extension of the image that I upload?

Tags: php, laravel

I uploaded a "jpg" file, then when it is being uploaded into my server it is changed as "jpeg"? How can I prevent Laravel from doing that?

This is my code:

```
$path = Storage::putFile('public/category', $request->file('image'));
$public_url = URL::to("/storage/category/".$request->image->hashName());
$category->picture_url = $public_url;
```

Here it is when I upload it:
[image]

When uploaded in the server:

[image]

Thanks.

Edit: I think the guys here don't understand what I meant about this question that's why they think someone answered this question already. So, I'm okay with Laravel changing the file name because it makes it safe to avoid duplicate file names. What I don't want for Laravel to do is change its file extension from JPG to JPEG.

Comment: Or this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43966895/custom-file-name-while-keeping-extension

Comment: You need a 3rd parameter to the `Storage::putFile` command. `Storage::putFile('public/category', $request->file('image'), $request->image->getClientOriginalName() . '.' $request->image->getClientOriginalExtension());`

Check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44531652/laravel-5-4-upload-original-file-name-and-extention

Comment: *The file's extension will be determined by examining the file's MIME type.* [Source](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem#storing-files)  Since `image/jpeg` can have both `jpeg` and `jpg` extension the first one is used by default. Use `putFileAs` for more control over the filename

Comment: I dont want to upload the original name. Im OK with Laravel renaming the file since that is safe so that no redundant images. I just want to avoid Laravel renaming the file extension from "jpg" to "jpeg".

Comment: @apokryfos - okay, i will try that. your comments much makes more sense :)